# lot more conditional execution in Java code

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

How to implement condition: a lot more, in Java 8?
I want to use a **"lot more"** condition like: 
`1.0 << 10000` in my algorithm.
How can I realize it?

```
assert d > Lambda: "The parameter d aren't much larger than Lambda, the method in section 7.3. not applicable";
```

How can I use check `d>>Lambda` in Java, `d>Lambda` is not best?

Comment: Well how about writing your own comparison method that can check whatever you want and returns `true` or `false`?

Comment: You probably should just avoid `assert`. Prefer Guava's [`Preconditions`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) and [related documentation on conditional failures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ConditionalFailuresExplained), or just use an `if (...) throw ...;` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use -ea flag to enable assertions. >> operator does not exist maybe you can implement some other logic as in x/1000>1, for instance.

```
~$ java -ea -classpath /home/admin Boo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: some text
at Boo.main(Boo.java:7)
~$ cat Boo.java 

public class Boo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int i =100;
  assert i < 99 : "some text" ;

} 

}
```

Comment: The definition is much larger - it is one or two orders of number... a ≫ b - means that a is much larger than b.